# Is there a way to detect whether the attached debugger is remote-debugger?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, remote-debugging

Using `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Debugger.IsAttached` I can tell that a debugger is attached. Is there a way to detect whether the attached debugger is remote-debugger (`Visual Studio Remote Debugger Monitor`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the native [`CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679280(v=vs.85).aspx) from `kernel32.dll`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679280(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The "remote" in CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent does not imply that the
>   debugger necessarily resides on a different computer; instead, it
>   indicates that the **debugger resides in a separate and parallel**
>   **process.**

You can use it as follows:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern bool CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent(IntPtr hProcess, ref bool isDebuggerPresent);

public static void Main()
{
    bool isDebuggerPresent = false;
    CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, ref isDebuggerPresent);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Debugger Attached: {0}", isDebuggerPresent));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```